# Java Guessing Game debugging issue I cant solve

Tags: java, debugging, for-loop

Okay so my guessing game is almost finished I just cant figure out why the middle part is not working. Basically the user enters a five digit number and it is supposed to take the number of digits in their guess and add their totals up as well as tell them how many digits they got correct so they can guess again however its not even running through my for loop any help would be appreciated.

```
//Jonathan
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

import java.util.Scanner;
public class Guessing 
{

public static void main(String[] args) 
{
  //JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Welcome to Jonathan's number guessing game.");
  int correctPosition = 0, sum = 0, numOfGuesses = 5, i;
  String usersGuess, secretCode;
  double number = Math.random() * 100000;
  number = Math.round(number);
  secretCode = Double.toString(number);
  do 
  {
    numOfGuesses--;
    System.out.println(number);
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    usersGuess = keyboard.nextLine();
    if (usersGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(secretCode))
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You got the number correct!");
        System.exit(0);
    }
    else if (!(usersGuess.equalsIgnoreCase(secretCode)))
    {
     for (i=0; i > 5; i++)
         {
            int digit = Character.getNumericValue(usersGuess.charAt(i));
            if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i))
            System.out.println(digit);
            {
                correctPosition++;
            }

         }
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "You have " + correctPosition + " numbers in the correct position." + " The sum of which are\n" + sum + " keep guessing!");
     }  
    }  while (numOfGuesses > 0);

  }  
}
```

Comment: Your for loop condition is incorrect, it should be i < 5. You should debug these kind of problems yourself by adding a debugger or using print statements around where you feel the code is not getting executed.

Comment: The lines following `if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i))` don't quite look right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several things stand out...

First...

```
for (i = 0; i > 5; i++) {
```

When `i` is `0`, `i` will be less then `5`, which means `i > 5` will be `false` and the loop will terminate...

I think you mean

```
for (i = 0; i < secretCode.length(); i++) {
```

If fact, because you need to compare each character in the `secretCode` and the `userGuess`, you actually need a compound loop

```
for (i = 0; i < secretCode.length(); i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < usersGuess.length(); x++) {
         //...
    }
}
```

Next, you are converting the `usersGuess` value to an `int`, but are comparing it to the `char` value of `secretCode`...

```
int digit = Character.getNumericValue(usersGuess.charAt(i));
if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i))
```

This will never be equal, instead, simply compare the `char` value of `userGuess` against the `char` value of `secretCode`

```
for (i = 0; i < secretCode.length(); i++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < usersGuess.length(); x++) {
        char digit = usersGuess.charAt(x);
        if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i)) {
            System.out.println(digit);
            correctPosition++;
        }
    }
}
```

Now, this might produce false postives, something more like...

```
for (i = 0; i < secretCode.length(); i++) {
    if (i < usersGuess.length()) {
        char digit = usersGuess.charAt(i);
        if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i)) {
            System.out.println(digit);
            correctPosition++;
        }
    }
}
```

might be more appropriate, but I would also add a `if` statement to check the `length` of the `usersGuess` to make sure it's equal to the the `length` of `secretCode` and display an error message if the user inputs an invalid value...which I kept doing...
And...

```
if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i))
System.out.println(digit);
{
    correctPosition++;
}
```

Which is actually executed as...

```
if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i)) {
    System.out.println(digit);
}
correctPosition++;
```

Which I don't think is what you want, I think you want something more like

```
if (digit == secretCode.charAt(i)) {
    System.out.println(digit);
    correctPosition++;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I got the code working